# local HTML to PDF using custom renderer only adds recently viewed images

Tags: html, objective-c, ios, pdf

here is a bit of a problem for you all. I have a html document stored locally on the device, with locally stored images (not in the bundle, on the disk). I present the html page in a UIWebView with an option for the user to convert the page to PDF and email the page. The pdf is generated with a UIMarkupTextFormatter and a custom UIPrintPageRenderer, NOT by making the webpage into an image and rendering the image to a PDF. This is because the PDF needs to be searchable.

Anyway, this was working just fine. However, the client has now requested that instead of just one page in the uiwebview, we instead have large pages broken up into paginated pieces. The export functionality still requires the entire web page not broken up into pages to be exported though.

The problem now occurs, that the exported PDF only has images for the currently displayed page. So for example, if I have the whole html page broken into 4 smaller pages, and the user is viewing page 3 when they press export, then the pdf will contain all the webpage information correctly but only the images that were on page 3. The pdf does not contain blank images, or malformed images, they are merely not present. If i then change to one of the other pages and export again, i get the images for that stage instead. The HTML is generated at the start so the only difference is the images are displayed or not.

Now, my guess is that the UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter is only displaying the images in the cache. This makes sense as a user generally wants to print a page that they see, so the renderer will not have to look beyond the cache for resources. The images in the html document have their paths pointing to the location of the file on disk, eg 'file:///var/mobile/Applications/C409BDBD-1254-4ADA-BAD8-F9BE5C171C93/Documents/Export/SoMeJobN/Images/915F0470-785D-40BF-A3E7-9945646843A7.jpg' and I have verified all the images exist at that location.

I have also overwritten NSURLCache and set a custom cache. I have found that the markupformatter is calling the

```
 -(NSCachedURLResponse *) cachedResponseForRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
```

method for each of the images in the webpage that are NOT on the current page, so it is asking for the asetts from the cache that are not on the current webpage!

I have tried to return the image loaded from disk with the following code.

```
NSString *pathString = [[request URL] absoluteString];


    // Load the data
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:pathString]];
            // Create the cacheable response
    UIImage *img  = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    NSLog(@"%@",img);

    NSURLResponse *response =
    [[[NSURLResponse alloc]
      initWithURL:[request URL]
      MIMEType:@"image/jpeg"
      expectedContentLength:-1
      textEncodingName:nil]
     autorelease];
    NSCachedURLResponse *cachedResponse =
    [[[NSCachedURLResponse alloc] initWithResponse:response data:data] autorelease];


    return cachedResponse;
```

and I have verified that the UIImage is loaded correctly, so the data is sound. But it is not showing in the PDF. So, does anyone have any ideas why this might be happening, have come across the problem before, or can think of anything else for me to try. I can refactor the code to load all the pages in series and export the parts of the PDF for each page, but this seems like an inelegant solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Recommendation: Before creating the pdf, do a `jquery.get(...)` call for the other pages.  Assemble them into a single html object in the proper order, and then send the html to your html-pdf converter via ajax, or via a javascript `form.submit()`

Comment: interesting approach. However i ended up just writing a module to convert a UIView heirachy into a pdf, and abandoned the html approach.

Comment: that sounds like it works better for your current situation.  I assume "UIView heirarchy" has something to do with IOS.  I'm not a mac guy, but I'm glad you found a good solution.